# How to Prove that Sum of all Inner Angles for ANY Triangle will ALWAYS be 180

Tags: geometry

My nephew in school was shown the following "magic trick" in his math class:

- If you draw ANY 3 points on a piece of paper and connect the 3 points, it will ALWAYS form a Triangle
- And if you measure and sum all the inner angles, they will ALWAYS sum to 180 degrees

My nephew was not really convinced about this and has been spent the weekend continuing to draw 3 points on different places on the paper and trying to somehow stumble across an exception to this "magic trick".

Watching him do this, I too have been wondering about a similar question : **How exactly would we prove both of these points? Are these points even provable or are these simply definitions?**

Can someone please help my nephew and myself? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik, they are definitions. Or more accurately, the sum of all the angles on a straight line is defined to be 180 degrees; the triangle angle sum follows from that. If you or your nephew have trouble deriving it, try visiting this site: https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/angle-sum-theorem/

Comment: they form an triangle iff the three points are not on the same line...

Comment: I don't quite know what the postulates are, but when I was in school, the following proof was given to us : if $A,B,C$ are three points, then draw a line parallel to $BC$ which passes through $A$. Use the fact that alternate angles (also known as $Z$ angles) are equal a couple of times and the sum of angles of $ABC$ is equal to a "straight" angle i.e. $180$ degrees. Another problem is that you and your nephew probably need different levels of convincing, because you're asking for a rigorous proof via some postulates, but your nephew may not want to believe those postulates as well!

Comment: It might be interesting to look at hyperbolic triangles (in which the angles add up to less than 180 $^\circ$), or elliptic triangles (in which the angles add up to more than 180$^\circ$). In general you could experiment with drawing triangles on curved surfaces, then you'll have found an infinite number of exceptions (which may not be the intended purpose), although on a flat plane the angles of a triangle will always add up to 180$^\circ$.

Answer (score 3):

Not a formal proof but hopefully can illustrate some intuition

Say the angles are $a$, $b$, and $c$. Walk from any point along the edges counter clockwise until you are back to the initial point and face the same direction that you start with

Notice:

- you make three left turn with angles $180-a$, $180-b$, and $180-c$
- you rotate yourself a total of $360^{\circ}$

$$
(180-a)+(180-b)+(180-c)=360
$$